# inheriting user controls

Tags: windows-runtime

For ease of management of a UI that has many elements shown as user controls, I would like my user controls to be inherited from a class of my own. So, in my user control, where there was:

Inherits UserControl

I changed it to

Inherits MyBaseUserControl

And I added a class MyBaseUserControl, which just inherits from UserControl.

It won't run immediately because the autogenerated intermediate file (.g.i.vb) for the UserControl inherits like this:

Inherits Global.Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.UserControl

.. but if I then edit the intermediate file to

Inherits MyBaseUserControl

it works great, I can effectively identify my own user controls and add properties and methods to them generically, which is exactly what I want to do.

But of course, if I edit the user control in the designer, the intermediate file is regenerated with

Inherits Global.Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.UserControl

I could manually edit the intermediate file whenever is gets recreated but it seems messy / dangerous.

Is there a way to do this properly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the UserControl strings in your XAML with MyBaseUserControl. E.g.

```
<controls:MyBaseUserControl
    x:Class="Sp.MyBaseUserControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:controls="using:Sp">
...
</controls:MyBaseUserControl>
```

Where `Sp` is the namespace that `MyBaseUserControl` is in.

Comment: So the first line of my Xaml is <UserControl . It's the only place I see UserControl. I change this to Sp.MyUserControl . Sp is the project name, I've tried it with and without this. Without it I get "the type was not found", with it I get "Nested types are not supported" . In fact, if I change it to Sp.AnyText, I get "Nested Types are not supported"

Comment: Well, in XAML you need to use custom XML namespaces for anything that's not from the platform's default namespace, so in your case you would need something like... let me update the answer for better formatting...

Comment: I found the answer but some idiot deleted it, I'll undelete it and see what happens - I can't undelete it because a moderator undeleted it - my answer was "Ok, got it, the syntax is local:MyUserControl, all works great now" - can anyone explain wy this would be deleted???

Comment: Because your answer is virtually identical to mine